# Change a make variable, and call another rule, from a recipe in same Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have already seen [How to manually call another target from a make target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377297/how-to-manually-call-an-other-target-from-a-make-target), but my question is a bit different; consider this example (note, stackoverflow.com changes the tabs to spaces in display; but tabs are preserved in source, if you try to edit):

```
TEXENGINE=pdflatex

pdflatex:
    echo the engine is $(TEXENGINE)

lualatex:
    TEXENGINE=lualatex
    echo Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check $(TEXENGINE) there!
```

Here, if I run the default target (`pdflatex`), I get the expected output:

```
$ make pdflatex 
echo the engine is pdflatex
the engine is pdflatex
```

But, with the target `lualatex`, I want to:

- change the `make` variable `TEXENGINE` to `lualatex`, and then
- call the same code as in `pdflatex` (which uses it).

How could I do that?

Clearly, in my `lualatex` rule I don't even manage to change the `TEXENGINE` variable, because I get this when I try it:

```
$ make lualatex 
TEXENGINE=lualatex
echo Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check pdflatex there!
Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check pdflatex there!
```

... so I would really like to know if something like this is possible in Makefiles.

Comment: For a start, I wouldn't call that target `pdflatex`, if you're using it to check arbitrary stuff.  I'd suggest something like `checkEngine`, and make it `.PHONY`.

Comment: Thanks, @OliverCharlesworth - I think that is fine, though, because `pdflatex` in this use case is the default, and so I get the same result for just `make` or `make pdflatex` (and the use case is then to change engines by specifying them as targets to `make`, as in `make lualatex`). Cheers!

Comment: Well, it's up to you ;)  (I'd find that rather confusing and bad practice...)  Can you just do `make TEXENGINE=whatever`, and structure a generic set of targets/rules that use the user-specified `TEXENGINE` variable?

Comment: Thanks again @OliverCharlesworth - I agree it would have been bad practice, especially for code building; but in this case, it will be very limited how this kind of a makefile would grow, so I'd dare ignore bad practices in exchange for command line convenience `:)` Otherwise, I'd forgotten all about variables on the `make` command line - just remembered while writing my answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use a [target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html)

> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable with their own target-specific variable value).

```
TEXENGINE=pdflatex

pdflatex:
    echo the engine is $(TEXENGINE)

lualatex: TEXENGINE=lualatex
lualatex: pdflatex
    echo Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check $(TEXENGINE) there!
```

The output is:

```
$ make pdflatex
echo the engine is pdflatex
the engine is pdflatex
$ make lualatex
echo the engine is lualatex
the engine is lualatex
echo Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check lualatex there!
Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check lualatex there!
```

Comment: Thanks for that @JonathanWakely - I was confused at first, because a prerequisite would call `pdflatex` before `lualatex`; but then I tested and realized splitting the `lualatex:` target in two avoids this pitfall - and the solution also works without recursive `make` call, which is great. Thanks also for the note on "target-specific variables". Cheers!

Comment: More specifically, if there isn't anything you need to do in `lualatex` that isn't just what `pdflatex` does then you don't need a recipe body on the `lualatex` target at all. Just the two `lualatex:` lines are enough.

Comment: can you have multiple variables defined?

Comment: @CpILL Yes, you can add multiple "lualatex: foo=bar" lines, each one for an additional variable. (I'm not sure if you can do multiple variables on a single line).

Comment: What if I want to call `pdflatex` from `lualatex` twice, with different variables?

Comment: @SOFe that seems like it belongs in a new question, not a comment. You could have the lualatex target depend on lualatex1 and lualatex2 targets, which each use a different override for the variable.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I managed to get to a sort of a workaround, but I don't exactly understand it much - so a more learned answer will be appreciated. For me here, these links helped:

- [Set a variable from within a rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019750/set-a-variable-from-within-a-rule)
- [make : rule call rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646688/make-rule-call-rule)
- [Passing additional variables from command line to make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make)

So here is the example modified - apparently, to call a rule from a rule afterwards (not as a prerequisite, rather, as a *post*requisite), I can only recursively call `make`, while having the new variable value specified on its command line:

```
TEXENGINE=pdflatex

pdflatex:
    echo the engine is $(TEXENGINE)

lualatex:
    echo Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check $(TEXENGINE) there!
    $(MAKE) TEXENGINE=lualatex pdflatex
```

The output is somewhat more verbose than I'd like it, but it works:

```
$ make lualatex 
echo Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check pdflatex there!
Here I want to call the pdflatex rule, to check pdflatex there!
make TEXENGINE=lualatex pdflatex
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp'
echo the engine is lualatex
the engine is lualatex
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp'
```

... which is what I wanted purely command-line interaction-wise, but I know is not the best solution (see @JonathanWakely's comment below)

Comment: What your rule does here is run another instance of `make` and explicitly override the `TEXENGINE` variable. Variables defined on the command-line take precedence over variables defined in the environment or in the makefile, so when the second `make` runs it uses the overridden value. The downside of this approach is you run `make` twice, so if it has to do a lot of work to check the status of prerequisites then you do all that work twice.