# Creating makefile with debug option

Tags: c, debugging, makefile

I have created a (very simple) makefile:

```
DEBUG = -DDEBUG

main: main.c add.c
   gcc $(DEBUG) main.c add.c -o main -lm
```

What I want (and don't understand how to do), is to create the makefile so that if the user prints `make debug`, the code will compile with the debug option, but when printing only `make`, the debug will be left out. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change a make variable, and call another rule, from a recipe in same Makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382846/change-a-make-variable-and-call-another-rule-from-a-recipe-in-same-makefile)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably are looking for something like

```
main: main.c add.c
   gcc $(DEBUG) main.c add.c -o main -lm

debug: DEBUG = -DDEBUG

debug: main
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. The only thing is that if i write 'make' then 'make debug' or the other way around, it still compiles to the first 'make' I write. Is it possible to create the makefile so that it recompiles with the option I give each time?

Comment: No, it doesn't compile to the first `make` you run. It simply checks if your source files are newer than your executable. If not, it won't do anything. So whatever `make` you run second will do nothing unless you update your source files in between. But if you want `make debug` to always recompile, simply add `.PHONY: debug`.

Comment: Adding `.PHONY: debug` won't help.  That just makes the `debug` target itself, which has no commands, phony.  You'll have to write a "clean" rule then run `make clean` between the two invocations of `make`.  Or, modify your makefile so the debug versions are created in a different directory.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for pointing that out. Apparently it worked when I tested it due to a change I forgot to revert back.

Comment: So instead of making `debug` phony, you could do `main debug: main.c add.c` in your first rule to make sure `make debug` always recompiles.

Answer (score 1):

This may be late, ...

The basic idea is to build all objects in the subdirectory, say `./build`.
We create a release file in ./build when we compile with `make` and create a debug file when `make debug`. So if there is a release file when `make debug`, remove everything in ./build and then build.

```
all: $(BD)/release $(bin1) $(bin2)

debug: CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG=1
debug: CXXFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG=1
debug: $(BD)/debug $(bin1) $(bin2)

$(BD)/%.o: %.c Makefile # changes in Makefile will cause a rebuild
    @mkdir -p $(BD)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BD)/%.o: %.cpp Makefile
    @mkdir -p $(BD)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BD)/release:
    @if [ -e $(BD)/debug ]; then rm -rf $(BD); fi
    @mkdir -p $(BD)
    @touch $(BD)/release

$(BD)/debug:
    @if [ -e $(BD)/release ]; then rm -rf $(BD); fi
    @mkdir -p $(BD)
    @touch $(BD)/debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, that depends on [bash variable substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Makefile:

```
main: main.c add.c
    ${CC} `echo $${DEBUG+-DDEBUG}` main.c add.c -o main -lm
```

When environment variable DEBUG is defined to anything (even blank), this makefile will substitute the `-DDEBUG` useful to the compiler. So invocation looks like:

```
DEBUG=1 make main
```